# Can't connect to internet (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, network-manager, internet

I've recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my desktop, with ***very*** little prior experience.

Anyways I can't seem to figure out how to connect to internet via any means whatsoever. The "Wi-Fi" tab in Settings just reads "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". I've tried using a wired connection to install possibly-missing drivers for the adapter; but plugging in an ethernet cable freezes the screen for some reason, and the only way to unfreeze is by pulling the plug and restarting.

I don't think it's a hardware issue, as everything worked perfectly fine on Windows (both wired and wireless).

here's the output for `sudo lshw -C network` (adapter details), if it helps:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 15
       serial: 4c:ed:fb:6b:f4:6c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a3204000-a3204fff memory:a3200000-a3203fff
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help, if anyone can figure out what might be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator I ran the command, not quite sure what to make of the outputs though.

Comment: There's a line with a <warn> that reads, "ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist", and also, "Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate", would these be significant?